# Use mixins with mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I would like to retrieve a full object composed of multiple mixins of its same type. For example a building `mall` is a mixin of `office`, `cantine`, and `store`. All of them are stored in the collection *buildings*.

I have the following scheme, where an attribute `mixins` is an array of other buildings:

```
BuildingSchema = mongoose.Schema
    _id:    String
    mixins: [String]
    title:  String
    attr1:  []
    attr2:  []
    attr3:  []

Building = mongoose.Model "Building", BuildingSchema
```

Is it possible (using some kind of static/instance method or using a pre/post hook) to retrieve and extend/overwrite the mixin objects with the *own* data to compose a final Building instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a static method called `retrieve` on the `Building` model, like so:

```
BuildingSchema.static "retrieve", (id, cb) ->
  @
    .findOne _id: id
    .exec (error, building) =>
      return cb error if error

      building = building.toJSON()
      mixins   = building.mixins or []

      async.reduce mixins, building, ((obj, id, cb) =>
        @retrieve id, (error, building) ->
          return cb error if error

          building = building.toJSON()
          building = deepExtend building, obj

          cb null, building

      ), (error, building) ->
        return cb error if error

        cb null, new Building building
```

Here, I'm basically calling the function `retrieve` recursively to enable mixins of mixins. The `deepExtend` function helps with the final object composition. In the end a new instance is returned.